# Allowing audio files in Spring MVC 3.0?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere

I'm using Spring MVC 3.0 where I specify the following `mvc:resources` tag to allow the static resources through:-

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

Somehow, I'm having problem getting my audio files to work. I decided to place an image file in the same location just to test the path and that works fine.

```
http://server/context/resources/test/image.jpg -> works fine
http://server/context/resources/test/audio.mp3 -> I get 404 error
```

I read the [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html) and it doesn't actually describe what's considered as static resources, and I would think the mp3 file is a static resource.

How do I get my audio file to work with Spring MVC 3.0? Thanks.

**EDIT**

My servlet.xml looks like this:-

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.project.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/app/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, perhaps problem is in something other.

Comment: jpg and js files work, but I can't get mp3 and wav files working.

Comment: There's nothing file-type-specific in how this works, you must have something else going on.

Comment: I just tried it in my coworker's machine, and it doesn't work too. If it helps any, I use Websphere Server here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often need to define this servlet for static content on WAS.  Try adding it for .mp3

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>static</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.SimpleFileServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

With the following mappings

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>static</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>static</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>static</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.mp3</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to register mp3 and swf here to get jPlayer to work... darn it.