# SpringMVC project Configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, flash

I have a **Spring MVC** project i have some resources like images and pictures that is being called by the application. I am getting a **404 Not Found Error** when i request the resources. E.g. I have a swf file his should be loaded with a page but it keeps giving the 404 message in **firebug**.

I have this file located outside the **WEB-INF** directory in a directory called swf. This was working previously and for some reason it stopped. Can someone assist me with the configuration details and location of where resources called by the application should be located. I am aware that files that the **Spring** container requests can be located inside the **WEB-INF** directory and all others must reside outside (i stand to be corrected on this).

**File Structure:**

```
-app
 -src
 -test
 -db
 -war
  -images
  -swf
  -WEB-INF
   -classes
   -css
   -js
   -jsp
   -lib
   -photos
   -tld
```

Comment: check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734458/how-to-access-the-images-from-jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something really wrong with your file structure. You have JS and CSS under WEB-INF folder. These files will not be accessible from web. Static contents cannot be placed under WEB-INF folder.

Structure your files, like this:-

```
-app
    -src
    -test
    -db
    -war
        - resources
            -images
            -css
            -js
            -swf
    -WEB-INF
        -classes
        -jsp
        -lib
```

Add this line to your `spring-servlet.xml`:-

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

With this, your base URL for all static contents become `/<context-root>/resources/`, ex: `/myapp/resources/images/test.jpg`.

Further, it is possible that your application server isn't configured to serve SWF file. So, if the image files work fine but the SWF files don't work, you may want to add the following mime type to your web.xml:-

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>swf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-shockwave-flash</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

**EDIT**

The solution to this problem is to write a small servlet to serve SWF file.

- If you are using Tomcat, you will need to write a small servlet to serve the static content... see this: [Servlet for serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content)
- If you are using Websphere, WAS has provided a built-in servlet to do the same thing... see this: [Allowing audio files in Spring MVC 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786602/allowing-audio-files-in-spring-mvc-3-0)

Comment: i am getting error: Flash movie not yet registered! for the swf file and 404 Not Found console error, any thoughts. I did restructure and configure my application as you indicated. The swf file turns on my webcam (http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/). Really need some help with this

Comment: The images are showing up fine and working however the console still shows the 404 error

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085562/jquery-webcam-plugin-error-flash-movie-not-yet-registered

Comment: I am not able to access any static contents using their base URL

Comment: That link doesn't help like i said i tried using the url for the static content and still it doesn't work

Comment: Are you able to hit `http://server/app/resources/swf/yourswf.swf` from the browser? Does that work? Is that the path you specified under `swffile` parameter for the webcam plugin?

Comment: What application server are you running on? Tomcat?

Comment: I am getting HTTP Status 404. Yes i am using TomCat 7

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content . You basically need to write a small servlet to serve SWF file. I had the same problem as this in the past, and in my case, Websphere provided a servlet to do just that. Here was my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786602/allowing-audio-files-in-spring-mvc-3-0

Comment: waw these worked really great man thank you so much you should update your answer with these links.